# how to get the database value to a String array in android(sqlite Database)

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, android-cursor

I have a database name "CUED" (sqlite Android)it have a table **HELLO** which contain a column *NAME* I can get the value to String from that column.
Let me show you my code section

```java
myDB =hello.this.openOrCreateDatabase("CUED", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
Cursor crs = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM HELLO", null);
                
while(crs.moveToNext())
{
    String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
    System.out.println(uname);
}
```

It will print the value one by one. Now what I need is that I want to get the column values from database and so that I can store it in a String Array.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You already did the hard part... the array stuff is pretty simple:

```
String[] array = new String[crs.getCount()];
int i = 0;
while(crs.moveToNext()){
    String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
    array[i] = uname;
    i++;
}
```

Whatever, I always recommend to use collections in cases like this:

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
while(crs.moveToNext()){
    String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
    array.add(uname);
}
```

In order to compare the arrays, you can do things like this:

```
boolean same = true;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(!array[i].equals(ha[i])){
        same = false;
        break;
    }
}
// same will be false if the arrays do not have the same elements
```

Comment: thank you bro  now can help me one more time i have another string array i want to compare both value in the array let me explain my first array--- String[] ha={"hello","hai"}; and String array from database----String[] array={"hello","hai"}; i want to check  the each position of both array if both are same let me enter next page

Comment: Good , but if  need to get all the column values from only one row  to form string array means  how to do ?

Comment: Hey, Great answer... What to do in case multiple rows are returned. ??




      String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("NAME"));

      String lname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("LASTNAME"));

Comment: Don't forget to `crs.close();`

Answer (score 0):

```
       String[] str= new String[crs.getCount()];
       crs.movetoFirst();           
     for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        { 
           str[i] = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
            System.out.println(uname);
      crs.movetoNext();
        }
```

Enjoy it

Comment: You are not moving the cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code that returns arraylist contains afield value:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllPlayers() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + serailnumber + " as _id, " + title
            + " from " + table, new String[] {});
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String uname = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(title));
        array.add(uname);

    }
    return array;
}
```